# Access App.js Constants in Controller and View

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js express app with a `app.js` file, a `deviceController.js` file, and a `cart.pug` file. I need to access two constants for the Stripe API in `deviceController.js` and `cart.pug` and want to set their values in `app.js`.

I tried `app.set/app.get` but get "app is undefined" in `deviceController.js` and I don't want to make a global variable with `var`.

What is the best practice way to do this?

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes/index');

const app = express();

// **want these constants available in deviceController.js and cart.pug** 
const keyPublishable = process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
const keySecret = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

module.exports = app;
```

deviceController.js

```
...
const stripe = require('stripe')(keySecret);
...
```

cart.pug

```
extends layout
...

block content
  .inner
    form(action="/payment" method="POST")
      script(
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key=keyPublishable 
        ...)
```

Comment: Since your variable are in `process.env` can't you just access them from `deviceController.js` ?

Comment: @WebRookie yes I could but I want to be able to set the constants to my live keys or test keys in app.js. Having them in just one place is beneficial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a module for your process constants - that way you can require them anywhere you want, without directly accessing process.

```
// constants.js

module.exports = {
  stripe: { // you could also use stripeKeys or whatever
     keyPublishable: process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
     keySecret: process.env.SECRET_KEY;
  }
}
```

then in each file

```
// deviceController.js
const { stripe } = require('./constants.js');
// use stripe.keyPublishable or stripe.keySecret
```

and in the templates

```
// when compiling the pug file, you also require the constants file and pass it
// template.pug has #{keyPublishable}
const { stripe } = require('./constants.js');
// .. rest of code
pug.renderFile('template.pug', {
  keyPublishable : stripe.keyPublishable 
}));
```

Check docs on how to pass objects to be interpolated by pug template